The computer caught someone mass downvoting all my posts
In two incidents, today and yesterday, someone methodically went down all my answers, and downloaded all of them 12 times. the computer detected both incidents and reversed the downvotes.
It seems to always happen in pairs of votes, so I suspect he might be a sock puppet also.

Can I find out who is doing this?

Can you?

Was he warned?

Can you warn him please?

Can he do it again with just a few downvotes and get away with it?

Why do I have to put up with this harassment here?



Have you read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me  and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting


Can I find out who is doing this?

No

Can you? Was he warned? Can you warn him please?

These questions are above my pay grade.  Mods may wish to answer.

Can he do it again with just a few downvotes and get away with it?

Up and downvotes are a core part of the way the site works.  There's nothing wrong with downvoting answers that are wrong, not useful or low quality. There is something wrong with downvoting an answer ad hominem. The system tries to correct such cases

Why do I have to put up with this harassment here?


Today you will be meeting with interference, ingratitude, insolence, disloyalty, ill-will, and selfishness – all of them due to the offenders’ ignorance of what is good or evil. But if for your part, you have perceived the nature of good and its nobility, the nature of evil and its meanness, and also the nature of the culprits themselves, (fellow creatures similarly endowed with reason and a share of the divine); none of those things can injure you, for nobody can implicate you in what is degrading.  (Adapted from Marcus Aurelius)

Being downvoted, and sometimes downvoted unjustly, is the price we pay for not being Yahoo Answers.
Be ruthless! Read you answers again.  If they are good then they are good and up/downvotes are meaningless. If they are bad then improve or delete them.
But really, I pray that the worst thing that happens to me today is serial downvoting, for that would be a good day.

== >nobody can implicate you in what is degrading.  == Hah! Thats how I pay the rent!
